# Converting old code. Indirection requires pointer operand

Tags: c

Have source for an old program that I need to compile using modern C compiler.  It's going berserk over this section:

```
/*
* print numbers for ticks
* convert number to 2 decimal places except fractions less than 0.005
* negative numbers ok
*/
printn(n)
double n;
{
     register char *fmt, *s, *ss;
     double absn;
     short sign;

     sign = n<0. ? -1 : 1;
     absn = n<0. ? -n : n;
     if (absn < 0.0000001) absn = 0.;

     /* if less than 0.005 then dynamically change the format */
     PPA[Phh*6)'sn < 0.005 && absn != 0.0) {
             short dec = 2;
             double nn = absn;
             while (nn < 0.005) {
                     nn =* 10.;
                     dec++;
             }
             fmt = "%-0.2f";
             fmt[4] = '0' + dec;
             s = printb(fmt, sign*absn);
             } else
             s = printb("%-0.2f", sign*absn);

     /* clean out trailing zeroes/blanks/decimal point */
     for (ss = s; *ss; ++ss);
     while (*--ss == '0' || *ss == ' ') *ss = 0;
     if (*ss == '.') *ss = 0;

     return(s);
}
```

Now I believe

```
PPA[Phh*6)'sn < 0.005 && absn != 0.0) {
```

perhaps due to some text conversion error should be:

```
if (n < 0.005 && absn != 0.0) {
```

but I'm also getting an "Indirection requires pointer operand ('double' invalid)" on:

```
    nn =* 10.;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Original operators were of the form `=op` but they were changed to `op=` to remove the ambiguity. More at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C

Comment: `fmt = "%-0.2f";
             fmt[4] = '0' + dec;` will attempt to write to read-only memory.

Comment: This is really, really old code. Like mid 1970's! Are you sure you want to use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nn *= 10.` will multiply `nn` by `10`

`nn = *10.` will try to dereference `10.`, which is invalid (being a double), like the error says.

Regarding indirection , the first search engine [hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw63e3c3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says:

The unary indirection operator (*) dereferences a pointer; that is, it converts a pointer value to an l-value. The operand of the indirection operator must be a pointer to a type. The result of the indirection expression is the type from which the pointer type is derived

In your case, the operand in `10.`, a double.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation which makes sense given what Omri said.